Beziér Curve to determine diameter of curve circle or torus arrays
I'm experimenting with a node based approach to build an object.
I want to create a beziér curve and mirror it (by modifier or geo nodes, main reason to be able to edit the curve later and the mirrored version being updated accordingly).
Now I want to be able to draw toruses via geo nodes that array along the z-axis, basically in between the mirrored curves. Every single torus diameter should then be auto calculated by the distance between the two curves.
I created a schematic drawing that (hopefully) explains everything. I also was able to create parts of it:
Arraying circles along a curve and calculating the diameter by the curves curvature (see attached). But I can't make the mirroring work. Just adding a mirror to the curve duplicates the array.
Maybe somebody has an idea or can help with the node tree setups :)





Not sure this is exactly what you want, but hope it helps.
Description:

I set lower spline resolution of the curve to get less dense points.

Duplicated the curve and scaled (transform geometry) to 0 along the X axis to get the circle centers and moved it to Attribute Statistic max X value of the original curve.

Sampled (sample index) point X positions of the original and scaled curve, then subtracted these values to get the circle radiuses.

Set the circle as instance on points of the scaled curve and used the circle radiuses as a scale.




UV Update:



Friend, you're a genius. I had to reconnect some of the nodes in the blender file you provided but with the help of your screenshot it was no problem at all. I added a curve to mesh node to add depth to the circle curves and it's exactly what I was looking for. Made my day!

Would there be a way to convert this to mesh then to be able to apply procedural materials?

With the materials and UV there is more complex approach and it can be achieved in more ways, you can find many tutorials FYI: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pzs_Uvb9DTg or Zeroskilz node https://blenderartists.org/t/curve-to-mesh-with-uvs-node-group-for-blender-3-0-4-0-geometry-nodes/1362714
